# how to center align a sub div

Tags: css, html

I need to center align a sub div within the parent div without using `text-align:center` / `align:center;`

Basically I tried the following example. I realise that in order for `margin:auto` to work, I need to specify a width (cannot use auto) into the sub div. But how can I do it if the sub div width varies from 0px to 500px?

see the example:

```
<div style="width:450px;height:500px;background:pink;">
    <div style="width:100px;height:200px;background:black;color:#fff;margin:auto;">
        hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So is the problem when the `width` of the "sub div" is greater than `450px`, this happens? http://jsfiddle.net/YHRmz/ Otherwise, can you explain more?

Comment: hi thirtydot, nope this happen when the width of the subDiv is auto. wat i meant is that the width of the subDiv is dynamic but its max width is 500px =)

Comment: Where does the `"sub div width"` come from? If you set `width: auto` on the "sub div", it will expand to the width of the parent element, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YHRmz/1/ :S

Comment: Why prevents you from using text-align to centre it?

Comment: I presume you are "allowed" to explicitely define `text-align: left` as that is the only way I can find around your dilemma...

Comment: As lpd said why not use an `aling="center"\text-align="center"`. You can set the parent div align to center then add `align/text-align="left"` on your subDiv.

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin: auto`, but to work you need to specify width of the div (as you do).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you can either use `margin:auto;`. You can also use:

```
margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
```

However it seems that your inner div is larger than your outer div. If you shrink the inner div it will work, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/TpFwh/4/

Answer (score -2):

You can use **center** tag to do it. After parent div tag use center tag.

Comment: @bazmegakapa : But nuttynibbles told that without align so deprecated can be used sometimes.